# How can I prevent ColdFusion from saying a defined variable is undefined?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

In our CF code, inside a larger page/application, we have a block something like this (minus the dumps to the page - they are logged to a DB table):

```
<cftry>
    <cfparam name="session.awesomeInfo" default="">
    
    <cfset somethingNew = session.awesomeInfo>
    
    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
        <cfdump var="#session#">
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

99.9% of the time, this works great. But once every few days, a user will hit this code and the `cfcatch` will be thrown. The `cfcatch` will point to the line with the `cfset`, and it'll say `Element AWESOMEINFO is undefined in SESSION.` However, there in the `session` that's dumped is `awesomeInfo`, right where it's supposed to be, with a non-null value. And, in the context of the page, it's after lots of other logic that looks at many other `session`-scoped variables without issue.

Any ideas what would cause this, or more importantly, how to prevent it from happening? It feels like maybe a server-level or CF-application-level problem. We're currently running Adobe ColdFusion 2018 Standard.

Comment: Looks like a racing condition to me. Is that code in your application.cfc? Do you have some concurrent request going on there, and have you tried to use cflock?

Comment: It's not in application.cfc.  I don't believe it's a race condition.  In the session dump, `session.awesomeInfo` is not set to the default empty string from the `cfparam`. It's set to another value that was set already from another page in an earlier request.

Comment: Someone elsewhere suggested this could be a false negative. It's saying the `session.awesomeInfo` is undefined, but it's actually a page timeout. There's a fair amount on the page, so there's a small possibility, with query slowness or something, the page may sporadically run long. Has anyone else heard of that?

Comment: "I don't believe it's a race condition." then you go on to describe a race condition ;-) If you set a shared variable at line x in some code, then require it to still be that value at line x+n and *don't lock the scope* across x-1 through to x+n+1, then you are opening yourself for a race condition (ie: some other request making its own changes to said shared variable between those two lines executing).

Comment: Thanks. The lock is worth a try. It's odd because there shouldn't be multiple simultaneous requests. Plus the value it's dumping in the cfcatch wasn't an empty string (as set by the cfparam), so it definitely wasn't set in the same request. It's set on another page in an earlier request. So, the variable would've had to have existed (as of the cfparam at the very least), been deleted from the session before the very next line to throw the error, and then be reset to the value from the 1st request in time to be dumped in the cfcatch, all by the same user.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it matters, but move the `cfparam` outside the try block.

If you're always passing a string, setting the ***type*** might prevent unwanted data types. You'll need to set in anywhere *session.awesomeInfo* is set using `cfparam`.

Here are two options you could use.

```
<!--- Moved outside try block --->
<cfparam name="session.awesomeInfo"  type="string" default="">

<cftry>
    <!--- Option A --->
    <cfif structKeyExists(session,"awesomeInfo")>
        <cfset somethingNew = session.awesomeInfo& " awesomeInfo Struct Key Exists.<br>">
    </cfif>
    <cfoutput>#somethingNew#</cfoutput>

    <!--- Option B --->
    <cfif isDefined("session.awesomeInfo")>
        <cfset somethingNew = session.awesomeInfo& " Session awesomeInfo isDefined.<br>">
    </cfif>
    <cfoutput>#somethingNew#</cfoutput>
    

    <cfcatch type="any">
            <cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
            <cfdump var="#session#">
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Comment: Thanks. Great ideas. Whenever I get this error, `session.awesomeInfo` is defined. For example, `session.awesomeInfo = "somethingAmazing"` in the dumps/logs. It doesn't equal an empty string, so the cfparam wasn't used. That doens't mean moving the cfparam won't have an effect, but it shouldn't.